# Как ускорить выборку данных из MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

У меня в таблице более 10000 записей. Когда я, с помощью запроса на php, вывожу циклом все данные на экран, скрипт примерно 20-25 секунд "думает", и только потом выводит данные. Подскажите, как уменьшить это время?

Comment: Используйте limit

Answer (score 1):

Время выборки зависит и от базы и от самого запроса. Проверьте время выборки на самом MySQL, прямо в консоли. Времена сравнимы с тем, что показывает скрипт?

Answer (score 0):

Ну сделать можно

```
ob_start();$out = ob_get_contents(); // результат можно в переменную засунутьob_end_flush();echo $out.
```

Собственно весь вывод сделать в самом конце, а данные как бы закешировать.

ps т.е. выводить все данные только потом а не сразу при обработке.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего у вас не скрипт глючит, а происходит передача данных от сервера к клиенту, ну и это, я конечно не знаю каким образом 10000 записей целиком выводятся на экран, но если через браузер, то странно, что он вообще не падает :)))) да и в любом случае, 10000 записей на экране это как бы немного перебор, вы так не считаете? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Кроме времени выборки в 25 секунд нужно учитывать особенность веб-сервера, который может сначала завершать выполнение скрипта, а потом возвращать ответ.

```
for ($i=0; $i<25; $i++){ print $i."<br />\n"; /* попробуйте раскомментировать и сравнить sleep (1); */}
```